# How to use multiple AsyncTasks

Tags: android, sockets, android-asynctask

I'm coding the client side of an Android application which uses sockets. Since I'm new with `AsyncTask`, I coded something simple to test my understanding. Here is what I have, it seems to be correct:

```
public class Messaggi extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

LinearLayout mLayout;
ScrollView scroll;
EditText writeMessage;
Button send; 
Socket connection;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_messaggi);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearVertical);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    writeMessage= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ScriviMessaggio);
    send= (Button)findViewById(R.id.invia);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    LavoraDietro asd = new LavoraDietro();
    asd.execute();   
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}

private void updateScroll(){ 
    scroll.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() { 
             scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
           }
        });
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText("Client: " + text);
    return textView;
}

private class LavoraDietro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String mex;
    @Override  
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){ 
        try {
            InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.79");
            Socket connection= new Socket(local , 7100);
              DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                output.writeUTF("Client: Server prova");
                output.flush();
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            mex= input.readUTF();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace(); 
            return false;
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        return true;
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result == true){
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("Sono connesso al server"));  
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("I canali sono aperi.."));
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mex));
        updateScroll();
        }
        else{
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("ERRORE CONNESSIONE AL SERVER "));
        updateScroll();
        }
        }
} 
}
```

When the connection to the server is established, the client sends a test meesage and the server should send the same message to the client, where it is printed.

But my task is to establish the connection immediatly when the app is opened and send a message only when the button "send" is pressed. Is possible to create multiple AsyncTasks and make them work at the same time without crashing the application? If yes, can you please post an example of how can I do this?

**EDITED CODE**

This is my new code:

```
public class Messaggi extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

LinearLayout mLayout;
ScrollView scroll;
EditText writeMessage;
Button send; 
Socket connection;  

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_messaggi);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearVertical);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    writeMessage= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ScriviMessaggio);
    send= (Button)findViewById(R.id.invia);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
    LavoraDietro asd = new LavoraDietro();
    asd.execute();   
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 CliccaInvia asd123 = new CliccaInvia();
    asd123.execute(connection);
}

private void updateScroll(){ 
    scroll.post(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() { 
             scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
           }
        });
}

private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText("Client: " + text);
    return textView;
}

private class LavoraDietro extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Socket> {
    String mex;
    @Override  
    protected Socket doInBackground(Void... params){ 
        try {
            InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.79");
            connection= new Socket(local , 7100);
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            mex = input.readUTF();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        return connection;
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(Socket result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result != null){
            mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("Sono connesso al server"));  
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("I canali sono aperi.."));
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mex));
        updateScroll();
        }
        else{
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("ERRORE CONNESSIONE AL SERVER "));
        updateScroll();
        }
        }
} 

private class CliccaInvia extends AsyncTask<Socket, Void, Boolean>{

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Socket... params) {

        try {
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.writeUTF("Client: Server prova");
            output.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
return false
        }
        return true;
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if(result == true){
        mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("Message Sent")); 

    aggiornaScroll();
    }
    else{
    mLayout.addView(createNewTextView("Error sending Mex "));
    aggiornaScroll();
    }
}

}
```

But this doesn't work.. :(

Comment: I dont know if I really understand what you want, what do multiple AsyncTasks have to do with showing a message when a button is pressed?

Comment: @tyczj I need to create a connection when the app is started, then I want to send the message only when I click on the button. Instead the code above creates the connection and immediatly send the message when the app is started. ( in few words I want to split these to actions: establish connection , send the message)

Comment: so why multiple async tasks? why not just use a boolean or something so you know if you are connected and on the button check the boolean to see if you should show the message?

Comment: @tyczj Because the message must be sent to the server before being displayed. So I need to send data when I click the button, so I have to open an AsynkTask in which I open the output Stream to send the message ( but when I tried to do this the app crashed)

Comment: what is your stack trace?

Comment: @WIllJBD
05-27 18:43:02.525: E/AndroidRuntime(27865): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: I need you to make an edit to your question and to post the full stacktrace, then we can help you better :)

Comment: You can very well use two async tasks. One for establishing the connection and the other to send a message upon a button clicked. But that is not multiple because at all times there is only one task. So why do you speak of `making them work at the same time`?

Comment: @greenapps Oh because I m new here and I don't know how to do this I tried something but FatalException occurred when I tried (because I write something stupid for sure).. so I thought that they had to work together. If it is not a problem can you please post an example.. Thanks very much for your patience

Comment: You are reading in your first asynctask. You said you only wanted to make the connection there. Never translate code. Copy and paste as is.

Comment: @greenapps Yes I want to read also when the app is started.. But The problem is the other AsyncTask the one which create the output when I click.. how can I fix it

Comment: Before we can continue I want to know what there is to read upon connection. You said before `when the connection to the server is established the client will send a message`. So we can conclude that there is nothing to read upon connection.

Comment: @greenapps When the message is sent,  the server read it and resend the same message to the client.

Comment: I know already. I read your explanation. But what is there to read upon connection?

Comment: Ok I fixed this.. now I can do everything without crashing the app, but the problem NOW is that in this way after the first message I can't send or receive other messages..

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need to spawn a lot of tasks and keep track of them all you could do something like this

```
List<LavoraDietro> tasks = new ArrayList<LavoraDietro>();

LavoraDietro task = new LavoraDietro();
task.execute;
tasks.add(task);
```

then in your LavoraDietro in the `onPostExecute`

```
tasks.remove(this);
```

But there is a million different ways you could make connections if you want. I recommend Apache's library. http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

Here is an example of how you might make a connection, just call this function from inside the background of your task.

```
public static InputStream getHTTPRequest(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> parameters, ArrayList<NameValuePair> headers)
    {
        final String TAG = "getHTTPRequest";

        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

        // attach all and any params
        if (parameters != null && parameters.size() > 0)
        {
            HttpParams params = getRequest.getParams();
            for (NameValuePair param : parameters)
            {
                params.setParameter(param.getName(), param.getValue());
            }
            getRequest.setParams(params);
        }

        // attach all and any headers
        if (headers != null && headers.size() > 0)
        {
            for (NameValuePair header : headers)
            {
                getRequest.addHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
            }
        }

        getRequest.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        getRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try
        {

            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "status not ok");
                Log.d(TAG, "status = " + Integer.toString(statusCode));
                Log.d(TAG, "url = " + getRequest.getURI().toString());
                return null;
            }

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            Log.d(TAG, "returning valid content");
            return getResponseEntity.getContent();

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: getRequest.abort");
            getRequest.abort();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what i was searcing for. I mean I know how to set up the connection beetween my client and my server (And this is what I did in the code I posted). What I have to do is to create a connection when the app is started (And this is not a problem because I ve already done in the code that I have posted) now I have to send a message ( for example "Hello World") to the server when my button is clicked.
(I am mortified for my bad English that has caused you a waste of time)